# Is it ok to take a 2-month-old baby out on fresh air?

Tags: newborn, clothes, temperatures

Is it OK to take a two-month-old baby out in fresh air and cool weather (14 C, 57 F) if properly warmed by adequate clothing? How long can the baby be outside?

Comment: Yes it is. http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-21537988

Comment: Absolutely. We took our kids outside a few weeks after birth. As long as you dress them appropriately for the weather it will be fine. Fresh air does us all good :)

Comment: 14 c is normal day time summer temperature here in Finland :) It's also normal for a baby to sleep outside if it is less than -30c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no inherent risk for even a newborn just from being outside, compared to being in a building, so **yes, it is ok**. As a matter of fact, exposing a small child to diverse environments (within reason) probably stimulates a healthy development.

That said, if there are *specific* risks associated with being outside, you should be aware of them and take appropriate precautions. Possible risks that come to mind are:

- exposure to cold (make sure the child is adequately clothed)
- overheating (same)
- sunstroke (same again, plus keep the child in the shade)
- very loud noises
- things that scare the child (depends on child)
- danger from motor traffic
- danger from animals (pet dogs or wild animals)

If you take precautions as necessary for your specific environments, I don't think there's anything to worry about.

Finally:

As a parent, remember that *your wellbeing* is also important. Not important enough to endanger your child, of course, but if a breath of fresh air helps you feel good, by all means take your child outside.